# Alternative to eval for multiple property lookup

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a a function that takes a string like `"obj.key.subkey.subsubkey"`:

```
function(obj, key) {
  return eval('obj.'+ key);
}
```

What would be a safe alternative to `eval` in this case or is `eval` fine? `new Function` won't work in this case AFAIK. Maybe `split` and loop then?

Comment: @Felix Kilng. Didn't see that one, that's what I was looking for. I expected to have to do something like that after all. Loop it is then...

Comment: I added it to my favorites because I can never find it either ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you really need a function here.  If you have the object and the key just use the key to return the property on the object.

```
obj[key]
```

If you must handle multiple keys:

```
function get(obj, key) {
  var keys = key.split(".");
  var tmp = obj;
  for (var x = 0; x < keys.length; x++){
     tmp = tmp[keys[x]];
  }
  return tmp;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/H55ka/

Comment: I ended up doing it like this but same idea, just to be able to chain it: `return keys.map(function(k) { return tmp = tmp[k]; }).pop()`

Comment: @elclanrs Nice! But from what I have read .map is only supported in IE >=9. Just so your aware.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @elclanrs: Note though that any of these solutions will throw an error if any key in the "chain" does not exist in the object.

Comment: This is basically for Node and ES5 so i'm good there. @FelixKling: Right, this is not an issue in my case because all the objects have the same keys but good to keep in mind.